# Extract a regex pattern from a specific column of a text file then perform a subtraction

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk

I have this text file

`cat file.txt`

```
8   Shawn   Arizona 45  father=Alex;NSM;GNO;One:0.9995,0.13|Two:0.9991,0.55|Three:0.9996,0.33|Four:0.9986,0.22|Five:0.9987,0.22
```

From the last column, I would like to extract the letters that precede the first of the floating number pairs -> s/(\w*:0.\d*

and then perform a replacement as follows:

```
8   Shawn   Arizona 45  First:0.9995|Second:0.9991|Third:0.9996|Fourth:0.9986,0.001386|Fifth:0.9987
```

And then subtract that number from 1 to get the following:

```
8   Shawn   Arizona 45  One:0.0005|Two:0.0009|Three:0.0004|Four:0.0014,0.0013|Five:0.0013
```

Can I use perl within an awk command similar to:

`awk 'NF=sys(perl -pe 's/(\w*:0\.\d*)/$1/g' $NF)'`

Is this easy to do in bash? I usually do not perform mathematical operations in bash, so am not sure how it handles floating variables

Comment: "extract the letters that precede first", by this  you mean to remove non-space characters before `Frist` ?

Comment: After `One:`, `Two:`, `Three:`, etc there are two floating numbers separated by a comma. ie `First:0.9995,0.13`. I wanted to keep the first of the pair (which comes before the comma)

Comment: Why `Fourth:0.9986,0.001386` has 2 numbers? Where does `0.001386` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task should be split into several parts: get line with data, remove undesired part, split data line into two blocks -- one to preserve and second block to manipulate, split second block into array, manipulate each element of array, merge preserved block and processed data for output

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = <DATA>;                  # gobble up line with data

chomp $data;                        # snip eol
my $data_orig = $data;              # store original data for comparison

$data =~ s/,\d\.\d{2}//g;           # remove second float numbers from data
$data =~ s/\b\w+=.*;//;             # remove unneeded part 

# now split into 2 blocks: 1 block to preserve, 2 block to operate on
my($block1,$block2) = $data =~ /(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+)(\S*)/;
#my($block1,$block2) = $data =~ /(.* )(\S*)/;   # other possibility of regex
my @data = split '[|]', $block2;    # get data of interest into @data array

@data = map {                       # manipulate @data array to subtract numbers
            my($n,$d) = split ':';          # get name and digit
            sprintf "%s:%.4f",$n,(1-$d);    # sprintf to preserve digit format
        } @data;

$data = $block1 . join('|',@data);  # combine preserved block and manipulated data

say $data_orig;                     # output input data for comparison with result
say $data;                          # output result and compare visually with original data 

__DATA__
8   Shawn   Arizona 45  father=Alex;NSM;GNO;One:0.9995,0.13|Two:0.9991,0.55|Three:0.9996,0.33|Four:0.9986,0.22|Five:0.9987,0.22
```

Output

```
8   Shawn   Arizona 45  father=Alex;NSM;GNO;One:0.9995,0.13|Two:0.9991,0.55|Three:0.9996,0.33|Four:0.9986,0.22|Five:0.9987,0.22
8   Shawn   Arizona 45  One:0.0005|Two:0.0009|Three:0.0004|Four:0.0014|Five:0.0013
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, tested and written on shown samples.

```
awk '
match($NF,/[a-zA-Z]+:[0-9]+.*,|[a-zA-Z]+:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.*,/){
  num=split(substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH-1),array,":")
  array[num]=1-array[num]
  for(k=1;k<num;k++){
    val=(val?val ":":"")array[k]
  }
  $NF=val":"array[num]
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

If Ruby is installed you could use:

```rb
File.open('input_file') do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    puts line.gsub(/,(\d|\.)*/,'') # remove comma when followed by numbers or dot
             .gsub(/\d\.\d+/) {|match| (1-match.to_f).round(4)} # substract numbers from 1
  end
end
```

To replace only the last line of the file:

```rb
puts IO.readlines('input_file')
       .last.gsub(/,(\d|\.)*/,'')
       .gsub(/\d\.\d+/) {|m| (1-m.to_f).round(4)}
```

Comment: you forgot to remove 'father=Alex;NSM;GNO;'

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
       RS="[|\n]"
       FS=OFS=":"
     }
     {
       nr=substr($2,1,index($2,",")-1)
       $2=1-nr
       printf "%s%s", $0, RT
     }' file
```

The GNU awk script relies on record separated by `|`.
The main statement is to extract the wanted number (the second field) and substract and replace it.
The last statement print the record.